# Does refraction take place in plane mirror?

Tags: reflection, refraction

I have read that reflection and refraction both occur simultaneously. My question is, does refraction also take place in plane mirror or is there only reflection?Why or why not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general when light strikes a surface, it can be transmitted, reflected, or absorbed. When light strikes at an angle, transmitted light changes direction if the index of refraction of the two media are different. This is called refraction.

At first glance, is sounds like a mirror reflects all light (except for a small amount of absorption), so there can be no refraction.

However, many mirrors are a piece of glass with a reflective coating on the back surface. So light can be refracted on the front surface, reflected from the back surface, and refracted again on the way out the front surface.

Comment: This is the accepted answer, but I give it a down vote.  Refraction occurs even at a metal  mirror.  The field inside the metal exists only in a thin layer near the surface, but it does exist, and its properties can be calculated from Snell's Law.

Comment: @garyp - You have a point. I had not considered that. If you are thinking about the physics of the thin film as in my2cts answer, you are right. But you typically don't when thinking about common everyday applications, such as the effect of the glass front of a mirror.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, refraction does occur. Consider a silver mirror (medium 2) which has $$n = 0.051585-3.9046i$$ at 587.6  nm (red). For perpendicular incidence from vacuum (medium 1), $$k_{2z} = nk_{1z}$$ so there is a wave with an overwhelmingly imaginary wave vector. Therefore the refracted wave falls off exponentially to zero in less than one wavelength. Still, it *is* a refracted wave.